# How not to overwrite randomly generated secrets in Helm templates

Tags: kubernetes, passwords, kubernetes-helm

I want to generate a password in a Helm template, this is easy to do using the `randAlphaNum` function. However the password will be changed when the release is upgraded. Is there a way to check if a password was previously generated and then use the existing value? Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-details
data:
  {{ if .Secrets.db-details.db-password }}
  db-password:  {{ .Secrets.db-details.db-password | b64enc }}
  {{ else }}
  db-password: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc }}
  {{ end }}
```

Comment: Generate & pass secret from outside

Answer (score 26):

You can build on [shaunc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435563/shaunc)'s idea to use the [lookup](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function to fix the original poster's code like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-details
data:
  {{- if .Release.IsInstall }}
  db-password: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc }}
  {{ else }}
  # `index` function is necessary because the property name contains a dash.
  # Otherwise (...).data.db_password would have worked too.
  db-password:  {{ index (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "db-details").data "db-password" }}
  {{ end }}
```

Only creating the `Secret` when it doesn't yet exist won't work because Helm will delete objects that are no longer defined during the upgrade.

Using an annotation to keep the object around has the disadvantage that it will not be deleted when you delete the release with `helm delete ...`.

Comment: While I do like this approach, it doesn't seem to work well with `helm lint`, `helm template` and `helm --dry-run` because it doesn't (and shouldn't) contact the Kubernetes API server to fetch the existing secret. The [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) state that "the `lookup` function will return an empty list (i.e. dict) in such a case". This results in "nil pointer evaluating interface" (when called without `index`) or "error calling index: index of untyped nil" when called with `index`. Ideas?

Comment: @riha I guess under `helm lint` all the fields in `.Release` are not setup, so the simple fix would be to replace `if .Release.IsInstall` with `if not .Release.IsUpdate` (well, avoid the negation and swap the two branches, but you get my point).
This change should also help with `helm template`.

Comment: Sorry, can no longer edit the comment; it should be `if not .Release.IsUpgrade`

Comment: I went with an assignment and a conditional. `{{- $data := (lookup ...).data -}}` and then `{{- if $data }}`. On another note: It seems to be a different story for `ConfigMap`s. When keys are entirely omitted in a Helm upgrade run, but present in the existing `ConfigMap` object on the cluster, they remain unchanged.

Answer (score 14):

I've got a lot of trouble with the answers from [Jan Dubois](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64325744/6537157) and [shaunc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555625/65371579). So I built a combined solution.

The downside of Jan's answer: It leads to errors, when it is used with `--dry-run`.
The downside of shaunc's answer: It won't work, because the resources will be deleted on `helm upgrade`.

Here is my code:

```yaml
# store the secret-name as var
# in my case, the name was very long and containing a lot of fields
# so it helps me a lot
{{- $secret_name := "your-secret-name" -}}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $secret_name }}

data:
  # try to get the old secret
  # keep in mind, that a dry-run only returns an empty map 
  {{- $old_sec := lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name }}

  # check, if a secret is already set
  {{- if or (not $old_sec) (not $old_sec.data) }}
  # if not set, then generate a new password
  db-password: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc }}
  {{ else }}
  # if set, then use the old value
  db-password: {{ index $old_sec.data "db-password" }}
  {{ end }}
```

Comment: It's a shame it doesn't work with upgrade dry-run. It makes it look like it's going to rewrite the secret but then it doesn't.

Comment: @Bufke There's no way it will ever work with `upgrade --dry-run` (where the `lookup` returns an empty dict) and randomly generated password. Should the generated password be a hash of some stable data relevant just for the release (e.g. release name, namespace), it could work. With the release name itself being randomly generated this should even be safe enough to use.

Answer (score 9):

It's still one of the biggest issues of Helm. As far as I understand no good solution is available yet (see https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/5167).

One dirty workaround is to [create secret as pre-install hook](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/5167#issuecomment-388833226). Obvious downside of this approach is that secret will not be deleted on helm delete.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "helm-random-secret.fullname" . }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
  labels:
    app: {{ template "helm-random-secret.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "helm-random-secret.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  some-password: {{ default (randAlphaNum 10) .Values.somePassword | b64enc | quote }}
```

Comment: I have a doubt about pre-install hook. What if you add new chart to requirements, that required new secret? You are using helm upgrade then, not helm install...
It looks for me there is simply no reasonable way to use generated passwords with helm (which makes me wonder, why they have added functions for generating random passwords in first line).

Comment: Helm supports pre-upgrade hooks as well.

Comment: Yeah this works as a charm already for few years

Comment: This is how Sentry's Helm charts work: https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/blob/develop/sentry/templates/hooks/sentry-secret-create.yaml

Answer (score 4):

Building on [shaunc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435563/shaunc)'s idea to use the [lookup](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function, I've created the following template:

```
{{/*
Returns a secret if it already in Kubernetes, otherwise it creates
it randomly.
*/}}
{{- define "getOrGeneratePass" }}
{{- $len := (default 16 .Length) | int -}}
{{- $obj := (lookup "v1" .Kind .Namespace .Name).data -}}
{{- if $obj }}
{{- index $obj .Key -}}
{{- else if (eq (lower .Kind) "secret") -}}
{{- randAlphaNum $len | b64enc -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- randAlphaNum $len -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end }}
```

Then you can simply configure secrets like:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  PASSWORD: "{{ include "getOrGeneratePass" (dict "Namespace" .Release.Namespace "Kind" "Secret" "Name" "my-secret" "Key" "PASSWORD") }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The actual tools are all here. My workaround is just another combination of suggested tools

```
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "mysecret") }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/resource-policy": "keep"
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: {{ randAlphaNum 24 }}
{{- end }}
```

So if there is no such secret, it will be created. If the secret is present, it will be removed from the chart, but not from the cluster, the `"helm.sh/resource-policy": "keep"` will prevent it.

You may ask (as someone already did above) why `lookup`, not `.Release.IsUpdate`. Imagine the situation: your secret is a password to a database. You keep the data in the persistent volume, the claim for which is also annotated by `"helm.sh/resource-policy": "keep"`, so if you even uninstall and reinstall the chart, the data would persist. If you do so with `.Release.IsUpdate` as condition, then you password will be recreated, the old password will be lost and you will loose the access to your data. If you query for the secret existence, it won't happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`lookup` function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) and skip generation if secret already exists:

```yaml
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "secret" .Release.Namespace "db-details") -}}
<create secret here>
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: I like this idea. Is there a reason to use `lookup` instead of `Release.IsUpgrade` ?

Comment: Hmm... well -- suppose the upgrade actually adds the secret? You could work around that but perhaps this is simpler.

Comment: Actually, this method doesn't work as intended. As @jan-dubois correctly pointed out in his answer below, the secret is deleted on upgrade if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Immutable Secrets https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#secret-immutable

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-database-password
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}-database
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
type: Opaque
immutable: true
data:
  db-password: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc | quote }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten kubernetes replicator and added some annotations to deal with this kind of problems: https://github.com/olli-ai/k8s-replicator#use-random-password-generated-by-an-helm-chart

Now can generate a random password with helm, and replicate it only once to another secret thus it won't be change by helm in the future.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: admin-password-source
  annotations:
    k8s-replicator/replicate-to: "admin-password"
    k8s-replicator/replicate-once: "true"
stringData:
  password: {{ randAlphaNum 64 | quote }}
```

Hope it will help people.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage definitions in the `_helpers.tpl`

### _helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{/*
Create the secret name
*/}}
{{- define "mssql-server.secretName" -}}
{{- include "mssql-server.name" . }}-mssql-secret
{{- end }}

{{/*
Get sa password value
*/}}
{{- define "mssql-server.sapassword" -}}
{{- if .Release.IsInstall -}}
{{ .Values.sa_password | default (randAlphaNum 20) | b64enc | quote }}
{{- else -}}
{{ index (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace (include "mssql-server.secretName" .)).data "sa_password" }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

### secret.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mssql-server.secretName" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "mssql-server.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
type: Opaque
data:
  sa_password: {{ include "mssql-server.sapassword" . }}
```

Answer (score -5):

A bit late here, and most people may just catch it in the documentation:

helm does this for you with the annotation `"helm.sh/resource-policy": keep`

see:

https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#tell-helm-not-to-uninstall-a-resource