# Assigning secret to user password

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a password secret which is stored in my cluster. My issue lies in setting that password as my default user's password without hardcoding it or it's encoded value. I think that the lookup function can be used here but it is not the right password which is being assigned to the default user.

I'm expecting to be able to use the encoded password to access my clickhouse pod inside my cluster but I'm not getting authenticated. I know the encoded password is:

```
$ kubectl get secret clickhousepassword -o jsonpath='{.data}'
{"password":"QlBRcnByZHdtTXZBSmRVWVM0Nng="}
```

Hardcoding the password like:
`default/password: QlBRcnByZHdtTXZBSmRVWVM0Nng=`
will work. But I'm not interested in doing that.

**Is there something that I am missing or any suggestions on how to do it another way?**

**my-secret.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
data:
  password: {{ randAlphaNum 20 | b64enc }}
```

**users.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: "clickhouse.altinity.com/v1"
kind: "ClickHouseInstallation"
metadata:
  name: "installation" 
spec:
  configuration:
    users:
      default/password:  {{ (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "mysecret").password }}
```

**Additional information:**

Output of `helm version`:

version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.4.2", GitCommit:"23dd3af5e19a02d4f4baa5b2f242645a1a3af629", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.13"}

Output of `kubectl version`:

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:17:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4+k3s1", GitCommit:"2532c10faad43e2b6e728fdcc01662dc13d37764", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-18T22:11:18Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: what is `user.yaml` in this case? what you are facing? this question needs more clarification I believe.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty Thanks addressing that. I have added more details and hopefully my question is more clear now.

Comment: Question is unclear regarding what you want. Do you want to access the password in your pod or do you want something else?

Comment: @AmitSingh I want to set the default user's password to be equal to the secret which exists inside my cluster.

Comment: Using a `secretRef` would be ideal, but I see that this is [not yet supported by the operator](https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/issues/386).

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake by using

```
 (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "mysecret").password
```

instead of

```
 (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace "mysecret").data.password
```

which is how to use the lookup function correctly according to how my secret is created. After correcting the mistake my encoded password got assigned to the user.

Comment: what will happen do the bounty ?

Comment: I don't know. This is the first time I've created a bounty on a thread. 
This thread is still open as the question also includes other suggestions of a solution to what I want to achieve. Maybe a suggestion not including the helm lookup tool.

Comment: I am not an expert on helm chart, but when you do a helm update the secret will be change no? so the user will have again a different password

Comment: @dreamcrash You're right. Next step for me from here is to not overwrite the existing secret like in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170052/how-not-to-overwrite-randomly-generated-secrets-in-helm-templates

Comment: Yes, exactly that what I have done also in a similar situation to yours

Comment: Np, hopefully you get either a good answer or enough votes to compensate the -100