# Helm and Kubernetes: Alternative to immutable ConfigMap with random value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a ConfigMap for a StatefulSet, within which I'm generating a uuid that, once generated, needs to stay the same across scale-ups/scale-downs, uninstalls, installs, etc. Pretty much the only time it should be regenerated is after an uninstall + all persistent storage being removed + the ConfigMap itself being removed as well, which would be rare.

The ConfigMap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: id-store
  annotations:
    helm.sh/resource-policy: keep
  labels:
    {{ .... }}
data:
  uuid: "{{ randAlphaNum 22 }}"
immutable: true
```

Now this seems to work, but seems like a bit of an anti-pattern. Helm gives an error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot patch "id-store" with kind ConfigMap: ConfigMap "id-store" is invalid: data: Forbidden: field is immutable when `immutable` is set
```

The deployment goes through and the ConfigMap functions as it should, with the value staying the same. But the combination of the `resource-policy` annotation and `immutable: true` might cause issues with `helm install --replace` (which we don't use currently), and that error message is unpleasant to have hanging around. We do use `helm upgrade`, and I'm not sure if this approach would be problematic for that command as well.

I can't be the first person to want a value to be generated once with Helm and not be re-rendered, so is there some more idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is this the same as [How not to overwrite randomly generated secrets in Helm templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170052/how-not-to-overwrite-randomly-generated-secrets-in-helm-templates)?  That has a couple of techniques, including generating the UUID in a pre-install hook and using `lookup` to find the existing value.

Comment: Thank you for that link, it was hugely helpful. My configmap ended up looking very similar to some of the answers in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to David Maze for the linked question in the comments, this config map ended up looking very similar to those. It only differs slightly because, in my case, the uuid is being used to set the Kafka cluster id - because the pods are in a StatefulSet, I need the config map to always persist unless explicitly deleted so that restarted or scaled up pods will use the same cluster id as is stored in existing PVCs. With this, the ConfigMap is only rendered if one doesn't already exist in the Kubernetes instance.

```yaml
{{- $deployed_map := lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" .Release.Namespace "id-store" }}
{{- if or (not $deployed_map) (not $deployed_map.data) }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: id-store
  annotations:
    helm.sh/resource-policy: keep
  labels:
    {{- include "kafka.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  uuid: "{{ randAlphaNum 22 }}"
{{ end }}
```

Without the `immutable: true`, the error message in my question disappears, and there seem to be no issues when running `helm upgrade` or `helm install --replace` as well.